# "Classpath is incomplete. Only syntax errors will be reported" in VSCode with Java Play Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-code

**First of all**: every answer I found on this error was about a Java file outside of a full project, this does not apply here.

I am trying to be back to an old java play project of mine, in play 2.6. I "Eclipsified" it with the `sbt eclipse` command. It was written in Java 8.

This is most likely a VSCode configuration problem since `sbt compile` runs smoothly on this project, the java play application runs and everything works fine.

My system is using OpenJDK 1.8 Globally. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

**My problem:**

At some point in my code I have these lines :

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

// some more code

return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> forbidden());
```

And VSCode gives me this error:

> The method supplyAsync(Supplier) in the type CompletableFuture is not applicable for the arguments (() -> {})Java(67108979)

Plus, when I open any Java file in my project, I get the following error:

> Classpath is incomplete. Only syntax errors will be reported

But in my project I do have the following Eclipse files

- `.classpath`
- `.project`
- `.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs`
- `.settings/org.scala-ide.sdt.core.prefs`

My class path includes, but is not limite to ([full classpath file here](https://pastebin.com/UGrp5mSj)):

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="app"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="conf"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="target/scala-2.12/twirl/main"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="target/scala-2.12/routes/main"/>
```

(All my source code is in `app`)

In my VSCode settings relative to Java, I have:

```
    "java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64",
    "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "interactive",
    "java.format.comments.enabled": false,
    "java.format.settings.url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml"
```

Note: The argument error pointed here is just an example, I have others such as:

```
return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Optional
            .ofNullable((Subject) ctx.args.get(ConfigKeys.SOME_CONFIG_KEY)));
```

Telling me:

> The method ofNullable(T) in the type Optional is not applicable for the arguments (Subject)Java(67108979)

I am pretty sure this is because my VSCode editor is badly configured since last time I worked on this project it was also with VSCode and I did not have this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved : the `sbt` extension in VSCode was causing some interference.

Comment: Reported similar issue on Github. can you please help in troubleshooting. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-dependency/issues/189

Comment: not sure how the issue on GitHub is similar, my Java Dependencies Folder seemed fined as far as I can remember.